# Neo4j bidirectional traversal sideselector max depth

Tags: neo4j, graph-traversal

I have huge graph which is densely connected and I have been trying to use Neo4j's bidirectional traversal framework for efficient path discovery between two nodes. I would be obliged if someone can explain the role maxDepth plays in sideSelector method. The only explanation I have been able to find is in the javadoc and it is very vague to me. 
The description in javadoc: maxDepth - optional max depth parameter to the side selector. Why is max depth a concern of the SideSelector? Because it has got knowledge of both the sides of the traversal at any given point.

How does having knowledge of depth affect SideSelector?

My current code looks like this:

```
        BidirectionalTraversalDescription description = graphDb.bidirectionalTraversalDescription().
    startSide(graphDb.traversalDescription()
                                .depthFirst()
                                .uniqueness(Uniqueness.NODE_PATH)
                                .expand(new RelsPathExpander(xxxx))
                                .evaluator(Evaluators.toDepth(3))).
    endSide(graphDb.traversalDescription()
                                        .depthFirst()
                                        .uniqueness(Uniqueness.NODE_PATH)
                                        .expand(new RelsPathExpander(xxxx))
.evaluator(Evaluators.toDepth(3)))
                                .collisionEvaluator(new Evaluator() {
                                    @Override
                                    public Evaluation evaluate(Path path) {
                                        return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
                                    }
                                }).sideSelector(SideSelectorPolicies.LEVEL, 100);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the author of parts of the traversal framework I think I recall that it's about a scenario where you have the two sides not specifying their own max depth, but instead there's one max depth in the side selector. This allows for a bit more dynamic traversals where one side could go much deeper than the other, say if there were were less relationships to traverse on one side compared to the other. This depth skew allows for cases where a traversal could complete w/ fewer relationships traversed than if both sides were descending at the same rate. [TraversalShortestPath](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.3/community/graph-algo/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphalgo/impl/path/TraversalShortestPath.java) uses this feature.

In your case you should just be able to set it high enough to accommodate both sides.